# Make winforms application run on other computer

Tags: c#, winforms, frameworks, build, .net

I developed a WinForms application (using C#, with visual studio 2008) and I have a few questions regarding how to build it properly:

1. Will the exe release file be able to run on other computer with only the required .net framework and not visual studio (or any other visual-ish program)? The exe file size is only around 50kb, which is way too small for such an application so I really doubt it. I did try this on other computer with .net installed and it seemed to work fine, just want to reassure that though.
2. Is there any way to include the .net framework functions that I use into my application so that it will run on any other Windows computer (with .net framework installed or not)? As in, include everything in a single exe file, just click-click and run.

**Edit**: When distributing the program, the 50kb exe file is enough, right? Or should I deliver the whole release folder?

Comment: 50kb is more than enough for a .net application. Don't forget that a large proportion of code is held in the .net framework assemblies and therefore doesn't add to your code.

Also...back in the day 50kb would have been considered a huge program!

Comment: Thanks. So should I just grab the EXE, or the whole Release folder?

Comment: First make sure you have compiled a release version. Then make sure that any non-standard assemblies have also be copied into the release folder. Then grab the whole folder, and you should be good to go.

Comment: What you don't need are those *.pdb and .vshost files, they are for debugging and will only bloat your setup.

Comment: What about the manifest files?

Comment: The exe file already contains the manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, your executable will run fine on another computer as long as it has the corresponding .Net package and any referenced assemblies.
2. No, there is no way to run your application on a machine without .Net installed. .Net is installed out of the box unless you're running WinXP. You can ship .Net installers with your app.

Answer (score 0):

Look at **ClickOnce** deployment

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.100).aspx

> ClickOnce is a deployment technology that enables you to create
>   self-updating Windows-based applications that can be installed and run
>   with minimal user interaction. Visual Studio provides full support for
>   publishing and updating applications deployed with ClickOnce
>   technology if you have developed your projects with Visual Basic and
>   Visual C#.

Comment: I tried that. But the process is confusing and not friendly at all. Even if everything's on my local machine, the setup file still tries to connect to the Internet (at least it seems that way). And BTW, I don't want a setup file, a stand-alone exe will do.

Comment: ClickOnce can be used to deploy apps on CD/DVD - without internet access.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and yes.

For the second part you can package the .NET framework with your setup project if you wish. Of course, this will make your distributable *much* larger, so you might want to think about whether that is better than just providing a download link to install the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

1)you need the exe AND ALL DLLs associated. All you need to do is grab the WHOLE debug OR release folder since this is the OUTPUT/ result of compiling your application.

2)If you write .net software you need the .net framework to run those applications.

Comment: That could be a bit misleading, normally you just need the exe file (and the dotnet framework of course) and there are a lot of other files in the bin\Debug folder. Only if you use third party libraries, you have to deliver their assemblies.

Comment: Someone could have a console application which uses a dll project in the same solution. Then the installer would need the exe and the dll.

Comment: @Adam Bruss - True, but user1065635 wrote, he tried the winform exe on another computer and it worked. Of course one has to deliver all referenced assemblies. I just wanted to say that there are other "unnecessary" files in that directory, which should not be in a setup.

Comment: I think that so long as the intention isn't to use the assemblys in another project, it is ok to copy the whole debug or release folder. I see what you mean though, in that you would never want to add certain files from these folders into source control, for other developers to rebase with

Answer (score 0):

About your first question, it seems just ensuring having related .net version loaded in the target machine is enough.
For the second question, as far as I know it is not possible to have a portable small set of .Net framework. You can enable the client to download framework on the other hand.

Answer (score 0):

For first question if it is working why you worry about size and size of compiled file quite small i have an exe for small ERP which is around 600 kb. although i have components which fill in.

Secondly you can publish you application using publish faicility incuded in visual studio. you can also include .net framework on customisizing publish.
Right click project>Properties>Publish

Comment: I doubted the size of the application because when I write console apps with C++, their sizes were always around 150kb. Thanks BTW.